# Scrapy shell does not return anything

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract organization names and basic details about them from this [website](https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organization.companies/a4037d74c4b824bda73299a91ce82defeff7ed8d) .I am using scrapy to extract information.I tried scrapy shell to extract first organization name  **TENCENT HOLDINGS** and have written scrapy command in scrapy shell as
`response.css('div.flex-no-grow.cb-overflow-ellipsis.identifier-label::text').extract_first()`
and this command returns nothing.I am a novice in web scrapping.Can anyone please help me in writing the command for it or rectify me where I am getting it wrong ?

Comment: when I tried to scrap your link in scrapy shell, I got response code 416 and a webpage saying " As you were browsing www.crunchbase.com something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen......". Basically, It is a security measure which you will need to bypass before you can scrap this website.
So, just check what your response text looks like before you start selecting elements to make sure you are solving the right problem.

Comment: Thank You fro responding.I am not getting any error response at Scrapy shell when I write my command it just returns nothing neither error response nor any result.How can we bypass this security measure using scrapy ?

Comment: run `print(response.text)` on scrapy shell and confirm if you are getting the actual webpage data or webpage with above message that I have posted.

Comment: Yes I got the same response as you indicated in your message how can we bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your website it's all up and running well, but there's an issue with the scrapy shell. scrapy shell passes the headers as `Scrapy/{version}(+http://scrapy.org)` and this website throws 403 error you can verify that by printing response object.

What you need to do is change the headers for the request, let say more appropriate headers `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}`
and pass it with the request then you'll get the response.

To try it in shell do this:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}
url = 'https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organization.companies'
```

Make a req as:

```
req = scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=headers)
fetch(req)
```

Now you will get 200 in response and use your CSS path.